# АПИ Гугл-таблиц

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Вот [здесь](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#properties) есть инструкция по работе с гугл-таблицами через gs.
Запускал через Инструменты - Редактор скриптов. Работает. 
Вопрос, как общаться с гугл-таблицами со стороннего ресурса? Необходимо брать значения из ячеек?

Answer (score 1):

Через REST-подобный API ([Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en)). Сразу предупреждаю, то что там наворочали, в т.ч. с OAuth, может вогнать в депрессию.

Comment: через php нельзя получается сделать?

Comment: Ну почему же: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

С помощью Гугл-скрипта можно сделать web-интерфейс к таблицам. Более точно это называется **"опубликовать Web приложение"** (Меню "Publish" - "Deploy as web app..."). А если подробнее, то нужно прочитать [соответствующую документацию](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). Судя по моей практике, делается совсем не сложно, и во многих подобных Вашему случаях годится как решение.

Всякий раз, публикуя web приложение, следует подумать о мерах безопасности. При публикации Вам придётся выбрать разрешения на доступ к приложению. Этим приложением мы открываем доступ не только штатным PHP серверам, но и потенциальным "врагам", способным украсть или даже повредить информацию в таблицах. Но Вы указали, что требуется только чтение - уже проще. Если не конфиденциально, можно открыть доступ "для всех" (украсть нечего). Если конфиденциально, можно предусмотреть дополнительные средства защиты. Скажем, шифрование... Вариантов много.